# How would I make webdriver selenium open another tab, and do something?

Tags: python, selenium, tabs, webdriver

How would I make webdriver selenium open another tab, and copy something from that another tab, close it and paste it in the first tab?

How would I do this?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that opens a page, opens a new tab, copies something, closes the tab, and pastes the text into an input field on the new tab:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page")
driver.switch_to.new_window("tab")
driver.get("data:text/html,<h1>Page B</h1>")
text = driver.find_element("css selector", "h1").text
driver.close()
window_handle = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
driver.find_element("css selector", "input").send_keys(text)
driver.quit()
```